# Imported .FBX file won't pack as resources

Tags: import, .fbx, blend-files, append

I downloaded a Free Wheat.fbx file and imported the content into blender.

I have toggled the Automatically Pack Resources on.

I try to save the file as a blend file, but it gives a warning that an image is missing (I believe it's an Image that was used as texture for the wheat)

Report Error: "Unable to pack file, source path......"

But the folder/path indicated (as missing) is not available in the downloaded folder.

My guess is that whom ever had made the Wheat.fbx file did not include the texture image.

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by Blender not packing an FBX. When you import an FBX, it adds the objects and its data blocs in the scene. The only data it could pack are for example texture files used in materials. These should be able to be packed. But the FBX file itself is not needed by Blender after import.

Comment: @L0Lock I will re-edit my question immediately. Please help me see to it again.

Comment: If there is an image your FBX file calls for but isn't provided, you can't do much about it. If you save your .blend file, then do file > Revert, do you get a "missing file" warning ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens if Blender cannot find an image on your storage drive. This is not uncommon when importing files and textures are missing. You can try using File -> External Data -> Find Missing Files to point Blender to a directory with all the textures. FBX format does not work perfectly with Blender so it is also likely some information about texture files might not import correctly and you might have to recreate materials manually.

See: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541).

As it is mentioned somewhere there, you can try using GLTF format instead of FBX if possible. A lot of software supports it and importing/exporting materials do work surprisingly well with it(as for something that usually doesn't work at all).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (since you haven't posted any pic) that when the original author created the file, he packed the textures inside the blend file properly. But when he uploaded it to another site, it might have gotten messed up if the site tried to read the blend file (for optimization) instead of just storing it as it is.

Most authors in anycase send textures in a separate folder as well (besides being inside .blend file). If you have those textures, just edit the image node in your material (which shows up pink in viewport) ..to the point it to the correct texture.